# Using internet causes glitches in playing music

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, audio

When I'm playing music on my laptop, using internet causes glitches (slight pauses and some noise) in the sound.

It's not because of high CPU usage, I tried playing music when converting 8 music files simultaneously and my CPU was 100% all the time, but the music was still playing nice.

Here's my system spec.:

- CPU: Intel Core i7 2670
- RAM: 8 GB
- Wireless adapter: Atheros AR9002WB-1NG
- Sound: Realtek High Definition Audio
- OS: Windows 7 Ultimate x64 (with all the updates installed)
- (My laptop is Asus N43-SN if helps!)

As I observed task manager doing some network activity (like opening lots of links), I saw some "spikes" in CPU usage and sound glitches at the same time.

First, I updated Realtek HD Audio, I think it made glitches less, but didn't make them disappear.

After that, when I was searching around to fix this, I found some article in Microsoft's website about registry entries about priority of handling multimedia interrupts. I tried to set all of them to highest possible and I think it was doing good for a week or two, and became the same after that.

I tried different music players, no difference.

As far as I remember I haven't had this problem when playing videos, even HQ videos.

I think the problem is caused by bad wireless adapter driver. (I tried to find the driver, but I couldn't find any reliable site to download it from. If someone can provide me an "official" driver, I would be grateful.)

Thanks :-)

Comment: What registry entries did you edit? What audio player are you using? If it has an option to specify the buffer size, try increasing it and see if that helps.

Comment: @karan I'm using Windows Media Player, and I didn't find anything related to buffer size (except network buffer size).

Comment: Try switching to a better player. :) I'm serious though, can you test with a portable install of foobar and see if the problem persists?

Comment: @Karan I tried different players and I believe this problem has nothing to do with my music player, because when my wireless adapter is off, it plays music without any problem. The problem lies in my wireless adapter.